# Does hiding image make loading faster?

Tags: wordpress, html

Does hiding the "featured" image on WordPress single post with `display:none` make the page load faster?

I understand the `img` tag is still loaded in the DOM, just wondering does it make any difference in download speed at all.

I need the "featured" image on post listing page, but not on single post.

Comment: FYI there is an extensive discussion on Stack Overflow about whether `display:none` prevents an image from loading in to the browser (which would make the page load faster). See: [Does "display:none" prevent an image from loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158540/does-displaynone-prevent-an-image-from-loading)

Comment: Why not have the image conditional on whether it's a list or a single post.  It would be safer than relying on each browser making the right decision, present and future!!!

Comment: This should also be moved to the WordPress section.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct. When you hide an image using CSS with `display: None`, The browser still loads the image, even if it isn’t rendered as visible on screen for the user.

All the resources mentioned in the HTML (i.e, images) will be loaded and pulled from the server by the browser even if they are not in view or you have used CSS to hide them on the webpage.

That involves the browser downloading the image file, which is costly on bandwidth and could result in bigger first load times of pages.

Comment: I think your answer is correct, save for the first sentence - which is the opposite of what the restr of your post conveys.